Squarespace section content getting reversed and order is changed in mobile view
I have a site that I am building
https://azalea-fiddle-5ha9.squarespace.com/
pwd: USTAX2024
On desktop, my site is fine, but when I view in mobile,  the section the title THE SOLUTION is appearing before THE PROBLEM. This should not be the case. On the desktop site, the order is fine, but on mobile it is switching up. How can I fix this?
This is what I have tried to add as Custom CSS to no avail:
@media (max-width: 600px) {
    #yui_3_17_2_1_1727035450177_100 {
        display: flex !important;
        flex-direction: column-reverse !important;
    }
}


I get Please try again. error with that password.

Password u provided doesn't work "ustax"

@DamianChudobiński  I have updated it

@mrconcerned updated it

Same error happens.

For password "USTAX2024" still error 400
"{"errors":{"password":"Invalid."},"error":"Form field errors."}"

@mrconcerned i have removed the need for a password

@DamianChudobiński no longer needs password

At this point flex-direction: column-reverse will be not best solution cause there are more then only those 2 items.
So i would go more like
    @media(max-width: 600px)
    {
        .customcontainer
        {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
        }

        .customcontainer > *
        {
            /* preserver rest of childrens after title and subtitle */
            order: 3; 
        }

        /* make title first */
        .customcontainer > .custom-title
        {
            order: 1;
        }

        /* make subtitle second */
        .customcontainer > .custom-subtitle-order
        {
            order: 2;
        }
    }

====================
Edit:
Theres a issue that this class is rendered dynamicaly (looks like its generated by and framework like vue, angular, react or something like this)
At this point we cannot use those id's/classes that are dynamically rendered each reload.
To style those elements you have to add an hardcoded class'es to keep styling.

I just tried this and nothing changes. I even tried adding !important and still nothing changes

Updated, you cannot use those classes as they are dynamically genereated each reload you need add your own classes to those elements.

I don't think you can add custom classes to elements in SquareSpace. Is it possible?

https://forum.squarespace.com/topic/151960-how-to-apply-custom-css-classes/ "Add your own custom class with styles in Design -> Custom CSS and then add a Code Block containing the HTML with your custom class assigned." If that aint work i can try tommorow make js to handle those styles (but this aint gona be very effective cause we gona have to find elements by text they have)
